# How to fix button in Selenium Python not clickable?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I copied the xpath of the button that downloads the csv of the lifetime concurrent players I want, but it's not working:

```
url = 'https://steamdb.info/app/730/graphs/'
try:
  driver.get(url)
except:
    pass

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0 , 750 );")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="highcharts-7mr3aoq-0"]/svg/g[11]/g/image'))).click()   

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="highcharts-7mr3aoq-0"]/div/ul/li[1]'))).click()
```

Comment: Seems like this page doesnt contains the id you are trying to reach. Can you recheck the id.

Comment: This is it: `image.highcharts-button-symbol`. It's the second button

Comment: This has class used only once in this page. You can use ```driver.find_elements_by_class_name("highcharts-button-symbol").click()```, to download the file. If multiple then create a list and get the 1st element

Comment: I get a `NoSuchElementException` when I tried this

Comment: Please check my question and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72784860/selenium-element-not-interactable-python/72785203#72785203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image` is svg element. use the following `xpath` to identify the element first and then click.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//*[name()='image'])[2]"))).click() //click image to open the link download csv  

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='Download CSV']"))).click() //click on download csv
```